# How to use a WF DelayActivity in an ASP.Net web based workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a web application that I am adding workflow functionality to using Windows Workflow Foundation.  I have based my solution around K. Scott Allen's [Orders Workflow](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/465.aspx) example on OdeToCode.  At the start I didn't realise the significance of the caveat "if you use Delay activities with and configure active timers for the manual scheduling service, these events will happen on a background thread that is not associated with an HTTP request".  I now need to use Delay activities and it doesn't work as is with his solution architecture.  Has anyone come across this and found a good solution to this?  The example is linked to from a lot of places but I haven't seen anyone else come across this issue and it seems like a bit of a show stopper to me.

Edit:  The problem is that the results from the workflow are returned to the the web application via HttpContext.  I am using the ManualWorkflowSchedulerService with the useActiveTimers and this works fine for most situations because workflow events are fired from the web app and HttpContext still exists when the workflow results are returned and the web app can continue processing.  When a delay activity is used processing happens on a background thread and when it tries to return results to the web app, there is no valid HttpContext (because there has been no Http Request), so further processing fails.  That is, the webapp is trying to process the workflow results but there has been no http request.

I think I need to do all post Delay activity processing within the workflow rather than handing off to the web app.

Cheers.

Comment: Whats the exact problem you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe the problem you are having. But maybe this is of some help.

You can use the ManualWorkflowSchedulerService with the useActiveTimers and the workflow will continue on another thread. Normally this is fine because your HTTP request has already finished and it doesn't really matter.

If however you need full control the workflow runtime will let you get a handle on all loaded workflows using the GetLoadedWorkflows() function. This will return acollection of WorkflowInstance objects. usign these you can can call the GetWorkflowNextTimerExpiration() to check which is expired. If one is you can manually resume it. In this case you want to use the ManualWorkflowSchedulerService with the useActiveTimers=false so you can control the last thread as well. However in most cases using useActiveTimers=true works perfectly well.